# How to choose between the changing consonants in the root?

Tags: відмінювання, приголосні, чергування

Is there any academic research on usage preference for alternating or static form of consonant on nouns?

For example, the noun *блок* and its Locative case — is it *у блоку* or *у блоці*?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The process of replacing `к` with `ц` is called [palatalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(sound_change)#Slavic_languages) of consonants. This is a typical process in Eastern Slavonic languages, although it has not fully completed in Russian.

In the work on Historic Ukrainian Grammar *Історична Граматика Української Мови* authored by L.P.Pavlenko, the three endings are deemed acceptable for masculine nouns of this form: *у блоку*, *у блоці*, and *у блокові*:

> У місцевому відмінку в сучасній українській мові виступають закінчення `-ові`, `-у`, `-і`, `-еві`, `-єві`, `-ї` залежно від групи іменників, які входять до цієї відміни... Так, за походженням `-ові`, `-еві`, `-єві` — це закінчення давального відмінка однини іменників з основою на *-ŭ ...
>
> Сучасне закінчення `-у`, `-ю` – це за походженням давнє закінчення місцевого відмінка однини іменників з основою на *-ŭ. В українській літературній мові вживається рідше, ніж `-ові`, `-еві`, хоча в окремих говорах, наприклад північного наріччя, може бути більш поширеним... Сучасне нормативне закінчення `-і` (на озері) розвинулося з давнішого закінчення `-ѣ`, що з’явилося за аналогією до твердої групи.

Answer (score 7):

There are several rules for changes of the consonanats.
The main changes happen in these consonants:
`г -> з`, `к -> ц`, `х-> с`  that occur in Locative and Dative cases, mostly at the end of the word.

Some changes may also occur in other parts of speech - like adjectives or verbs.

Further reading: [Чергування приголосних звуків](http://www.dilovamova.com/index.php?page=4&dmua=8&tdmua=%D7%E5%F0%E3%F3%E2%E0%ED%ED%FF-%EF%F0%E8%E3%EE%EB%EE%F1%ED%E8%F5-%E7%E2%F3%EA%B3%E2)

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, this is not *an academic research*, however, I'd like to mention *Український правопис* as an option. Among others, there are some sections, which describe the noun cases and declensions and provide examples of all possible alternations.Mine is ISBN 5-12-004853-6 Інститут Мовознавства (1996) and seems to be too old, but I'm pretty sure there should be a new one, printed during some last years.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case it should be *у блоці* - you can lookup in a dictionary like http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/ .

Generally, I believe if there are alternative endings for noun cases, any of those could be equally used. Unfortunately I cannot provide academic sources for this statement.