# У(в) чи На - поза політикою. У Фейсбуці чи на Фейсбуці, в Україні чи на Україні, в еміграції чи на еміграції?

Tags: відмінювання, прийменники

Ох, вже цей **Фейсбук**, особливо його місцевий відмінок.

Якщо із закінченнями більш-менш з'ясували [в попередніх запитаннях](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-to-choose-the-changing-consonants-in-root) (і Олександр Пономарів, і Олександр Авраменко допускають обидва варіанти - *Фейсбуку/Фейсбуці*), то з прийменником складніше.

Професор [Пономарів](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blogs/2013/11/131125_ponomariv_blog_ko) віддає перевагу прийменнику **`"на"`**.

А от доцент [Авраменко](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23VwXeAjtOY) вживає **`"у"`**.

Особисто я тяжію до **`"у"`**, бо ***у*** соціальній мережі, як і ***у*** Твіттері.

А чи є якесь правило, яке б поставило крапку у цьому ***"фейсбучному"*** спорі, а також у  заполітизованій дискусії - ***в Україні чи на Україні***, та де гірко-солодко - ***в еміграції чи на еміграції***?

Comment: _якщо є аккаунт у фейсбуці, то можна казати `на`, а якщо немае - то тільки `у`_

Comment: ще цікавить вживання `у еміграції` / `на еміграції`

Comment: @Chizh Чому саме так "якщо є аккаунт у фейсбуці, то можна казати на, а якщо немае - то тільки у"? А щодо еміграції, то я б ніколи не сказала "на" (виключно інтуїтивно).

Comment: вживання в [інтернеті](https://day.kyiv.ua/uk/article/kultura/ukrayinski-molodizhni-organizaciyi-na-emigraciyi) і [літературі](http://svit.gov.ua/index.php?productID=780) рідко, але все ж таки зустрічаються

Comment: @Chizh стосовно книги О’Коннор-Вілінська Валерії "На еміграції", то мені здається, що це такий літературний прийом - алюзія  чи що. Так і проситься "на чужині", наче авторка саме це хотіла сказати, тобто в еміграції, як на чужині. Але це моє суб'єктивне враження. Книгу цю я не читала.

Comment: [Володимир Потульницький](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80_%D0%90%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) у ["Дипломатії Павла Скоропадського"](http://acta.com.ua/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage-ask.tpl&product_id=100&category_id=11&option=com_virtuemart&Itemid=63&vmcchk=1&Itemid=63) сторінці 23 вживає: "... Ці акції В. Липинського кладуть початок організауійному рухові гетьманців на еміграції"

Comment: хоча там само на сторінці 26: "... і сам Павло Скоропадський і далі піддтримував вже стосунки вже в еміграції"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Коротка відповідь

Шукайте ключове слово для перевірки.
Якщо Фейсбук — це **веб-сайт**, то усталеним є вираз ***на** веб-сайті {Фейсбук}*, а значить, і ***на** Фейсбуці*.
Але якщо Фейсбук розглядається як **спільнота** (користувачів) або **комуна** (інфраструктурна одиниця, *community*), то усталеним можна вважати вираз ***у** спільноті {Фейсбук}*, а значить, і ***у** Фейсбуці*.

---

### Довга відповідь

#### 1. У чому полягає проблема

1. Ми не можемо добрати прийменник, тому що не можемо встановити, які просторово-суб'єктні відносини ми маємо із Фейсбуком у той час, коли *користуємося* ним.
2. **А чому — саме прийменник?** Адже термін *«під час користування Фейсбуком»* цілком виконує цю функцію:

   > *Ми познайомилися **під час користування** Фейсбуком…*
   > ***Під час користування** Фейсбуком, мій друг написав, що…*

   Відповідь: тому що цей термін не є лаконічним, і тому ми намагаємося добрати **короткий прийменник** «в», «на», і нас навіть влаштувало б «над» чи «під».

#### 2. Аналіз проблеми

1. Встановлення **категорії просторово-суб'єктних відносин** із Фейсбуком залежить від **граматичного змісту** самого терміну *Фейсбук*.
2. **Граматичний зміст** можна розглядати як сукупність **граматичних категорій** (ГК). Є три усталені граматичні категорії — род, число, відмінок, але також є і інші ГК, у тому числі — ГК просторово-суб'єктних відносин, яку ми шукаємо.

#### 3. Граматична категорія роду

Тут варто зробити невеличкий відступ і знов поглянути на три основні ГК, а саме — на категорію *граматичного роду*. Існують дві широко відомі проблеми:

1. Визначення граматичного роду **запозичених топонімів**;

   - Міссісіпі «став чистішим», «стала чистішою» чи «стало чистішим»?
   - Кіліманджаро «високий», «висока» чи «високе»?
2. Визначення граматичного роду **абревіатур**.

   - ООН «прийняв», «прийняла» чи «прийняло» рішення?
   - ОПЕК збільшив чи збільшила видобуток нафти?
   - СРСР напав чи напало на сусідню державу?

Для цього є відомий механізм — знайти **ключове** слово.

- Для топонімів:
  Міссісіпі — це **річка**, Кіліманджаро — **гора**, значить ГК роду — жіночий;
  Мічіґан як **штат** — чоловічий, а як **озеро** — середній тощо;
- Для абревіатур: ООН — це **Організація** Об'єднаних Націй (жін.),
  а СРСР — це **Союз** (чол.)

Тут детальніше (англійськов): [In languages with grammatical gender, how do they determine the gender when a new word has been created?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/3046/1009)

#### 4. Рішення

ГК просторово-суб'єктних відносин нічим не гірша, ніж ГК роду.
Тому для її визначення також можна користуватися методом пошуку ключового слова.

*Фейсбук* може вважатися *веб-сайтом*, і тоді відношення ***на веб-сайті** Фейсбук*, або ***на** Фейсбуці*:

> ***На** Фейсбуці можна лайкати дописи користувачів*.

Або може вважатися *спільнотою* користувачів, і тоді — ***у спільноті** Фейсбук*, або ***у** Фейсбуці*.

> *Цю думку я прочитав **у** Фейсбуці*.
> *Ми познайомилися **у** Фейсбуці*.

#### 5. На/в Україні

Усе те саме стосується проблеми «на/в Україні»:

- Якщо *Україна* — це суверенна держава, то **в**:

  > *Посол США **в** Україні*;
  > ***В** Україні відбувається зростання економіки*;
- Якщо *Україна* — земля, територія, край — то **на**:

  > *«…**на** Вкраїні милій»* — славнозвісне Шевченкове

---

#### Література

- [Анатолій Загнітко — Теоретична граматика сучасної української мови. Морфологія. Синтаксис.](http://litmisto.org.ua/?cat=4)
- [«Як ми говоримо» Антоненка-Давидовича](http://slovopedia.org.ua/34/53411/33342.html)

Comment: Це як англійське on/in [internet]

Comment: "Ми познайомилися під час користування Фейсбуком…" - звучить так, ніби ми обидва користувалися різними (кожен своїм власним) Фейсбуками, і так випадково познайомились. Так само можна сказати і "під час вживання попкорну" (знову кожен свого). Тобто "під час" не вказує прямо на роль самого Фейсбука як інструмента (для знайомства). Тому якщо йдеться про питання "за допомогою чого", то я б запропонував "Ми познайомилися через Фейсбук".

Comment: Щодо ролі Фейсбука як місця, припускаю, що стосовно віртуального простору прийменники "у(в)/на" цілком рівноправні. Розрізнення на "у(в)/на" виникає через розрізнення людиною типу локації в залежності від геометричного сприйняття її нею: "у(в)" означає обмежену область, заключену в конкретні межі (в котру можна ввійти і з неї вийти) або точку, а "на" означає поверхню (оболонку), відтинок, тобто множину точок. (1)

Comment: Оскільки візуальне сприйняття Фейсбука у кожного своє, то хтось уявляє його як віртуальну кімнату, куди можна ввійти (login) і з неї вийти (logout), а хтось як площу з неозорими межами, де знаходиться безліч людей і один з одним спілкуються. Тому перший буде використовувати "у(в)", а другий "на" і обидва матимуть рацію. (2)