# Чи є прийменник "на" властивим українській мові для використання із назвами міст або країн

Tags: прийменники

Нещодавно натрапив у Лесі Українки на такий фрагмент:

> **Іван**
>
> — Ба, яка ти горда.
>
> **(До Степана).**
>
> — У вас там *на Москві*, либонь, дівчата так бришкати не сміють?
>
> **Степан**
>
> — Я московських дівчат не знаю.
>
> **Оксана**
>
> — Як же се?
>
> **Степан**
>
> — Я, власне, недавнє *на Москві*. Поки ще батько живі були, я *в Києві*, в науці, при Академії здебільше пробував, а вже як батько вмерли, я
>   поїхав до матері на поміч.

Бачимо "на Москві", але "в Києві". Можливо, хтось може пояснити

- Чи є це просторіччям?
- Можливо мається на увазі не місто, а ріка як синонім однойменного міста?
- Або ж використовувати "на" із містами чи місцевостями є чи було нормою?

Comment: Related: https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/488/

Answer (score 1):

Тут йдеться не про Москву, як місто, а як про місце заробітку. І відповідно їдуть куди? - на заробітки. Тому і виникло таке сполучення, як "на Москву", "на Польщу". Також прийменник "на" вживається поряд з містами чи країнами, коли йдеться про напрямок, а не точку призначення: Поїзд на Москву. Також у відношенні до військових походів: Похід на Москву (Сагайдачного до прикладу)....

Comment: Гадаю тут все ж йдеться про Москву як Московщину/Московію, тобто країну/територію.