# Загальна назва слів, що описують відносну позицію

Tags: прийменники

Чи є в українській мові загальна назва для слів, що передають відносну позицію. Наприклад,

> 'А' *позаду* 'Б', а 'В' *попереду* 'Б'.
>   Стеля *над* столом, а підлога *під*.

Comment: Англійською це звучить як *spatial prepositions* можливо українською можна сказати *просторове розташування*

Comment: @Yola, [preposition](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposition_and_postposition) — [прийменник](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Прийменник). Просторові прийменники. (Хоча в українській мові такі слова не завжди вважають прийменниками, іноді частину з них в певних випадках вважають прислівниками.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

З морфологічної точки зору (тобто — поділу на частини мови), вони називаються [прийменниками **зі значенням простору**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B9.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.B7.D1.96_.D0.B7.D0.BD.D0.B0.D1.87.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F.D0.BC_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.80.D1.83).

З лексичної точки зору (тобто — функціонально, за своїм інформаційним змістом), це лексеми, які визначають [**граматичну категорію**](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F) ([англ.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_category)) **просторово-субʼєктних відносин** — тобто, яким чином два обʼєкти розташовані один відносно іншого у просторі.

Ще трошки подробиць у [цій відповіді](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/653/8).

Comment: За першу частину відповіді — «плюс». А от до чого тут граматична категорія — не зовсім зрозумів. (Тобто, може, й правильно — але поза моїм розумінням.)

Comment: Все одно незрозуміло. Що таке граматична категорія, я розумію — ну, там: рід, число, відміна, відмінок, час, доконаність/недоконаність, ступінь порівняння тощо; припустимо, ще якісь категорії, яких у нашій мові немає. Але от категорія просторово-субʼєктних відносин… Ви можете навести приклади таких категорій? От, наприклад, слово «шафа» (щось може лежати і в ній, і на ній, і під нею, і за нею і т.д.) — яка в цього слова категорія просторово-субʼєктних відносин (чи в кожному контексті різна)?

Comment: @Sasha, це виходить за рамки запитання, тому, напевне, варто оформити це у виді окремого запитання. Але коротко — це досить схоже на ступені порівняння. Так само, як дієслово «повʼязує» два обʼєкти за допомогою дії, так і прийменник повʼязує два обʼєкти через їхнє взаємне розташування. Стаття у Вікіпедії сама по собі доволі розлога, а ще й містить посилання на академічні джерела, підручники тощо.

Comment: Просто не зовсім зрозуміло, що мається на увазі під «визначають граматичну категорію …». Мається на увазі «належать до граматичної категорії …?».